# manipulate body of file object after browser upload

Tags: javascript, json, file, csv

When uploading a text [file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) to the browser I want to check the file content and manipulate it, where neccessary, before sending it to the web service.

**Additional Details:**

I'm uploading standardised csv files which and I want to add the first line which contains the meta info, in case it's missing. After that I'm deserializing the csv into an array of json objects, whereas the attributes are named after the meta info.

**Edit 1: Added Code, Library & Framework Information**

I'm using meteor, and I use [papaparse](http://papaparse.com) to transform the data from csv to json.

View:

```
  input(type='file' name='import idx' class='myFileInput')
```

JS:

```
'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
  FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    console.log(file); // works; contains a FILE object
    // TODO: check if file has a valid structure & add the meta data if it's missing
    var REObjects = Papa.parse(file, {              
        delimiter: "#",
        header: true,
        complete: function(results, file) {
            console.log("Parsing complete:", results, file); // works, contains JSON data
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: wait, do you send CSV or JSON to the server?

Comment: JSON (I upload the csv file and transform it into a json)

Comment: you have it as a string just before JSON.parse() right? just check that string and prepend the head if needed before parse()ing

Comment: actually I'm using a 3rd party libary, called *papaparse* to transform the data from csv to json, so I'm not sure if I can hook that at some point..

Comment: well you can probably feed it a Blob() instead of a File() and it won't notice. there's also ways to construct File()s in newer browsers. you should mention libs used in your question too. some code or a demo would help a lot too.

Comment: I never worked with Blob(), how can I tell my <input type='file'... to upload a blob?

Comment: you can't. you use a FileReader to get the File (which is really a decorated Blob), then make some changes, then create a new Blob with the result and feed that to your thing that's expecting a File. if you need to mock the input, just use `{files:[myBlob]}`

Comment: here is something for you to read: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files
lies de guide.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
  FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    console.log(file); // works; contains a FILE object

    // declare the first line of the file object
    var metaInfo = "some#delimited#meta#info#";

    var blob = new Blob([],  {type: "text/plain"});

    // construct blob object        
    blob = new Blob([blob, metaInfo], {type: "text/plain"});
    blob = new Blob([blob, file], {type: "text/plain"});

    // pass blob to parser library
    var REObjects = Papa.parse(blob, {              
        delimiter: "#",
        header: true,
        complete: function(results, file) {
            console.log("Parsing complete:", results, file); // works, contains JSON data using the metaInfo as attribute names
        }
    });
 });
}
```

special thanks to *dandavis*